# CSS Distance Between Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these bootstrap HTML divs:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel"><h3>6<br></h3>BIDS:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel"><h3>47.5<br></h3>LOWEST:<br></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel"><h3>49<br></h3>AVERAGE:<br></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel"><h3 class="text-bold">51<br></h3>HIGHEST:<br></div>
        </div>
```

Now I try to make the distance between the divs so I add to .mypanel class - margin-left, so:

```
.mypanel{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

But now I can't put it into one row, because 4 divs go below other divs... how I can fix that?

Comment: "But now I can't put it into one row, because 4 divs go below other divs" please elaborate...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Uk9iz3t.png

Comment: Okay, so are you saying that you want the divs to be inline, not block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve this is to put another `div` inside your `.mypanel` and give it a margin. This way, you can style your elements within the bootstrap grid, but without disrupting the bootstrap structure itself.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xum6preq/)

Something like this:

```
.mypanel{
  ...
}

.mypanel > div {
  margin: 0 15px;
  ...
}
```

You can now adjust the margin by just changing this value.

Check the full demo below:

```css
.mypanel{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.mypanel > div {
  margin: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel">
    <div>
      <h3>6<br></h3>BIDS:
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel">
    <div>
      <h3>47.5<br></h3>LOWEST:<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel">
    <div>
      <h3>49<br></h3>AVERAGE:<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center mypanel">
    <div>
      <h3 class="text-bold">51<br></h3>HIGHEST:<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```